# Can I use html / schema.org to control which image is selected by Outlook Web Applications link preview

Tags: schema.org, outlook-web-app

In the outlook web app, you get a preview when you put a URL into the body of the text.  In this preview, there is an image.

Can I do anything with schema.org etc. to control which image is selected from my page, to be used in this preview ?

My boss wants to send links for his website with the previews in the emails.  At the moment the previews are showing an image which is the logo for an a 3rd party which is about half way down the page.  My boss would like the preview to show the logo for the event, which is reasonable, as long as I can control which image is shown by the previewer.

I have tried to use the google url shortener on all but one of the images on the page, as I read somewhere that that might help, but the original image stubbornly remains in place.